# What RegEx separates terms of Polynomial

Tags: java, regex

I have a String **5x^3-2x^2+5x**
I want a regex which splits this string as
**5x^3,
-2x^2,
5x**

I tried `"(-)|(\\+)"`,
but this did not work. As it did not consider negative power terms.

Comment: What about: `-5x^-3+6x^2`

Comment: For my program there is no negative power

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split your string using this regex,

```
\+|(?=-)
```

The way this works is, it splits the string consuming `+` character but if there is `-` then it splits using `-` but doesn't consume `-` as that is lookahead.

Check out this Java code,

```
String s = "5x^3-2x^2+5x";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.split("\\+|(?=-)")));
```

Gives your expected output below,

```
[5x^3, -2x^2, 5x]
```

**Edit:**

Although in one of OP's comment in his post he said, there won't be negative powers but just in case you have negative powers as well, you can use this regex which handles negative powers as well,

```
\+|(?<!\^)(?=-)
```

Check this updated Java code,

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("5x^3-2x^2+5x", "5x^3-2x^-2+5x");
for (String s : list) {
    System.out.println(s + " --> " +Arrays.toString(s.split("\\+|(?<!\\^)(?=-)")));
}
```

New output,

```
5x^3-2x^2+5x --> [5x^3, -2x^2, 5x]
5x^3-2x^-2+5x --> [5x^3, -2x^-2, 5x]
```

Comment: But for `"5x^3-2x^-2+5x"` it gives `[5x^3, -2x^, -2, 5x]` which OP is specifically concerned about when they say "but this did not work. As it did not consider negative power terms"

Comment: @xtratic: I think user said in his comment that there is no negative power but doesn't matter, it can be easily handled. Let me update my solution for that as well.

Comment: +1 With your modification, this is probably the best method so long as the polynomial is in normal form, without double signs or any inner sums or differences, which I expect it is.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe,

```
-?[^\r\n+-]+(?=[+-]|$)
```

or some similar expressions might have been worked OK too, just in case you might have had constants in the equations.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0sQazm/1/)

#### Test

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class RegularExpression{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        final String regex = "-?[^\r\n+-]+(?=[+-]|$)";
        final String string = "5x^3-2x^2+5x\n"
             + "5x^3-2x^2+5x-5\n"
             + "-5x^3-2x^2+5x+5";

        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
            for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
                System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
            }
        }

    }
}
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/0sQazm/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/0sQazm/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

In below program , You can get break of every single variable. So debug it and combine regex as you need it. It will work fine for all input.

```
import java.util.regex.*;

class Main
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String txt="5x^3-2x^2+5x";

    String re1="([-+]\\d+)";    // Integer Number 1
    String re2="((?:[a-z][a-z0-9_]*))"; // Variable Name 1
    String re3="(\\^)"; // Any Single Character 1
    String re4="([-+]\\d+)";    // Integer Number 2
    String re5="([-+]\\d+)";    // Integer Number 1
    String re6="((?:[a-z][a-z0-9_]*))"; // Variable Name 2
    String re7="(\\^)"; // Any Single Character 2
    String re8="([-+]\\d+)";    // Integer Number 3
    String re9="([-+]\\d+)";    // Integer Number 2
    String re10="((?:[a-z][a-z0-9_]*))";    // Variable Name 3

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(re1+re2+re3+re4+re5+re6+re7+re8+re9+re10,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(txt);
    if (m.find())
    {
        String int1=m.group(1);
        String var1=m.group(2);
        String c1=m.group(3);
        String int2=m.group(4);
        String signed_int1=m.group(5);
        String var2=m.group(6);
        String c2=m.group(7);
        String int3=m.group(8);
        String signed_int2=m.group(9);
        String var3=m.group(10);
        System.out.print("("+int1.toString()+")"+"("+var1.toString()+")"+"("+c1.toString()+")"+"("+int2.toString()+")"+"("+signed_int1.toString()+")"+"("+var2.toString()+")"+"("+c2.toString()+")"+"("+int3.toString()+")"+"("+signed_int2.toString()+")"+"("+var3.toString()+")"+"\n");
    }
  }
}
```